# How to change default language of paginate functionality in larvavel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

When we use paginate() in Eloquent ORM then at the user side we got something like this

[image]

Is it possible to change the language of "Show" and "entries"?

if yes, then how??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set language option on DataTable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        }
    } );
} );
```

> Docs: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html